# pdf is not a valid media player type

Tags: primefaces

I am getting an error: "pdf is not a valid media player type" in Primeface

Answer (score 1):

Set it as mentioned below, in .XHTML

```
<p:media value="/resources/Eclipse_Shortcuts.pdf" width="100%" height="300px" player="pdf" />
```

And call / refresh the page you are done.

primefaces-3.4.2.jar: has fixed this. :):)